# Cannot save data to shared preferences / user defaults of app group

Tags: swift, macos, sharedpreferences, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I need to save some settings which should be shared among two apps. To achieve this I activated `App Groups` in the capabilities of both apps and set the App Group to `TeamIdentifierPrefix.name.appname`.

The relevant code to save the data in the user defaults:

```
let kListArray = "list"
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "TeamIdentifierPrefix.name.appname")
let data: [String:Any] = ["str1" : textInput.stringValue,
                          "str2" : button.state,
                          "str3" : ""]
let array = defaults?.array(forKey: kListArray)
var mutableArray = array
mutableArray?.append(data)
defaults?.set(mutableArray, forKey: kListArray)
```

Though when I have a look at the plist in `~/Library/Group Containers/TeamIdentifierPrefix.name.appname/Library/Preferences/TeamIdentifierPrefix.name.appname.plist` via Finder, it remains empty.

In Xcode get the follow warning in the Console:

```
2017-06-07 20:27:10.207748+0200 appname[3106:394220] [User Defaults] Failed to read 
values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x6080000e2b00> (Domain: 
TeamIdentifierPrefix.name.appname, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, 
Container: (null)): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only 
allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd
```

Comment: You aren't even supposed to access that path.

Comment: Sorry my words might have been a little bit misleading. I updated the question. Of course, I do not try to access that path with my app. I just had a look at the file via Finder, to check if the data has been saved.